# segue only works on swipe of cell but not tap

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a tableview (dynamic) which when tapped is meant to go to the detail view for each cell.

It doesn't move to the detail view if i tap the cell, but does if I swipe the cell.. its very strange.

I did copy this cell from another cell on a different view originally - I'm  not sure if that has something to do with it.

The original view (with the tableview) still works as normal, when tapped it goes to the detail.

The second screen only goes to the detail when swiped.

I have checked the properties, both are "show" segues on selection.

One other point, the first (working) one is from a cell in a TableViewController, the second is from a cell in a TableView.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had a searchbar on the page which had a tapgesture recogniser to dismiss keyboard when tapped anywhere else.

Removing this sort the issue!